# Getting a Dropbox URL in an Android app

Tags: android, dropbox, dropbox-api

Messaging apps on smartphones allow "attachment" of pictures on Cloud services like DroopBox but they don't provide a metaphor to get the URL to the picture.  I don't want to send big fat pictures (or videos) when I can just send a URL.

I have a messaging app that runs on Android (SafeTalk for Android).  Right now getting a cloud URL in my app works the same way it does on all other messaging apps - the user has to get the URL into the clipboard on his own ahead of time then paste it in.  That's very cumbersome and ugly.

I want to take the user through a metaphor that allows him to choose a cloud file and then get the URL magically into his text message.  Much the same way he now finds a file on Dropbox to attach.

So where would I go to find the right API to accomplish my task?
Thanks,
Dean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly what you're trying to do, I think you want the Chooser: https://www.dropbox.com/developers/dropins/chooser/android.

Essentially:

```
new DbxChooser(APP_KEY).forResultType(DbxChooser.ResultType.PREVIEW_LINK)
                       .launch(MainActivity.this, DBX_CHOOSER_REQUEST);
...
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == DBX_CHOOSER_REQUEST) {
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            DbxChooser.Result result = new DbxChooser.Result(data);
            Log.d("main", "Link to selected file: " + result.getLink());
        } else {
            // Failed or was cancelled by the user.
        }
    } else {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response.  Their example says I need a "Drop-in app" which take me to some arcane process that goes nowhere.  What's that all about?  I just want to implement the chooser for my android app.

Comment: "some arcane process that goes nowhere" -- https://www.dropbox.com/developers/apps/create, click "Drop-ins app", and then enter a name for the app. That's the whole process. :-)

Comment: OK, I see. that's how I get my APP_KEY. Thanks for pointing my to the right place.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Dropbox Android SDK](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/start/android#listing)
There are API for listing, to take file url